# Shell command to search a string in many files with same name located in different folders

Tags: ubuntu, grep, find, command

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have many files named "urls.py" in many folders. I want to search a particular string named "unit/" in these files. Can anybody tell me the command to search the same?

Comment: `grep "unit/" $(find /path/to/parent/dir -name "urls.py")`

Comment: @savanto : it worked for me. Thanks man. I used `grep -rin 'unit' $(find -name "urls.py")`

Comment: The `-r` is redundant as the `find` already produces the precise list of file names to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep -in 'unit' $(find -name "urls.py")` Works.